# Getting "SocketException Connection Reset" while invoking Jenkins API

Tags: java, rest, jenkins

I have a sample Java Program which connects to a particular Jenkins URL connection and calls one API. The program was working few days ago, but suddenly it has started showing `SocketException Connection Reset` for all the calls. I am unable to figure out what configuration has gone for a change in Jenkins Config.

Note: The below piece of code is working for all other URLs except this Jenkins setup. What could have gone wrong? Even I am able to call the API via postman.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static String getReq(String URL, String serviceName) {
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            URL obj = new URL(
                    "https://jenkins.abcdef.com/cid/jobs/abc/config.xml");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getReq(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are missing a:

`con.connect();`

right before this line:

`int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();`

Comment: I have added that line, but it results in the same Connection reset problem.